# Getting SSL error while installing intel driver

Tags: c, networking, ubuntu-16.04, drivers, ubuntu-server

While installing a intel Driver by doing `sudo make install` getting the following error-

- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
  sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory

Any Solutions for it?

Comment: *Which* Intel driver? What source repo or tarball are you using exactly?

Comment: any update on this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

Using 
Using DKMS Solved my problem when installing v4l2loopback
solution is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) 

`sudo cp -R . /usr/src/v4l2loopback-1.1
sudo dkms add -m v4l2loopback -v 1.1
sudo dkms build -m v4l2loopback -v 1.1
sudo dkms install -m v4l2loopback -v 1.1`

u may need to install dkms using
`sudo apt install dkms`